# Updating fields in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update fields my in 2 tables. But calling the save methods on each object isn't working. However, when I return them I see that the fields were updated in Postman.

```
User
public function update(Request $request, $visit_id){

        $visitRegister = FP_Register::where('visit_id', $visit_id)
        ->first();

        $visitPatient = FP_Patient::join('fp_registers', 'fp_registers.patient_id', 'fp_patients.id')
        ->where('patient_file_id', $patient_file_id)
        ->orWhere('fp_registers.contraceptive_method_id', $contraceptive_method_id)
        ->first();

        
        if(isset($contraceptive_method_id)){
            $methods_array = json_decode($visitPatient->methods_used_previously, true);
            $methods_array = [...$methods_array, $contraceptive_method_id];
            $visitRegister->contraceptive_method_id = $contraceptive_method_id;
            $visitPatient->methods_used_previously = json_encode($methods_array);
            $visitRegister->month = $currentMonth;
            $visitRegister->year = $currentYear;
        }

      
        if (isset($request['duration_days']) || isset($request['next_appointment_date'])) {
            
            $visitRegister->duration_days = $request['duration_days'];

            $durationDays = is_int($request['duration_days']) ? 
                strval($request['duration_days']) : $request['duration_days'];

            
            if (ctype_digit($durationDays) && intval($durationDays) > 0) {

                $durationInDays = intval($request['duration_days']);
            
                $currentDate = new DateTime();
                
                $nextAppointment = clone $currentDate; 
                
                $nextAppointment->add(new DateInterval("P{$durationInDays}D"));
                
                $visitPatient->next_appointment = $nextAppointment->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                
            }else if($request['visit_duration'] !== 'permenant'){
                $visitPatient->next_appointment = $request['next_appointment_date'];
            }
            else{
                $visitPatient->next_appointment = null;
            }

        }
        
        $visitPatient->save();
        $visitRegister->save();
        
        //return response()->json(
            [
                'PATIENT VISIT' => $visitPatient,
                'VISIT REGISTER' => $visitRegister
            ]
        );
    }
```

what am I doing wrong that is preventing the fields from updating in those 2 tables (fp_patients and fp_registers) in MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

In your code at the start you are trying to find using `$patient_file_id` or `$contraceptive_method_id` in your where clauses. They aren't referenced anywhere, so I guess there is no `$visitPatient`.

Try updating your code to use `firstOrFail()` at least then you'll get an error if the where fails.

On a side note, look into [validation and request classes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation), you should never trust direct input from the request

Comment: I've the `$patient_file_id` or `$contraceptive_method_id` defined already. I just had to cut them from the question lest it just be code and refused to submit.

Comment: @Mo1 hard to debug if all code not there, are you getting objects returened from your queries? Do you drop into your `if` statements?

Comment: I solved the issue. I was mistakenly out the the `->select()` method which caused the return of wrong model instances. 

Thanks for your willingness to help.